# Start systemd service from C/C++ application or call a D-Bus service

Tags: unix, service, process, dbus, systemd

I have a .service for a process that i don't want to start at boot-time, but to call it somehow from another already running application, at a given time.

The other option would be to put a D-Bus (i'm using glib dbus in my apps ) service file in /usr/share/dbus-1/services and somehow call it from my application. Also, i don't manage to do this either.

Let's say that my dbus service file from `/usr/share/dbus-1/services` is `com.callThis.service`
and my main service file from `/lib/systemd/system is com.startThis.service`

If i run a simple introspect from command line:

```
/home/root # dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply \
--dest=com.callThis  /com/callThis org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

the D-Bus service file will get called and it will start what is in the Exec ( com.starThis ). The problem is that i want to achieve this from C/C++ code using D-Bus glib.

Comment: Did you try to implement it? Show some first steps you did. Plenty of documentation and even a example can be found http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusConnection.html

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/dbus/ Here is info on `systemd`'s DBUS API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of [g_dbus_connection_send_message](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusConnection.html#g-dbus-connection-send-message) with [g_dbus_message_new_method_call](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusMessage.html#g-dbus-message-new-method-call) or [g_dbus_message_new_signal](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusMessage.html#g-dbus-message-new-signal) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble to do the same thing. The discover of : G_BUS_NAME_WATCHER_FLAGS_AUTO_START solve it.

```
g_bus_watch_name(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, "com.mydbus.listen",
      G_BUS_NAME_WATCHER_FLAGS_AUTO_START, xOnNameAppeared, xOnNameVanished,
      this, nullptr);
```